# How can I extract text before a character or string in a batch file?

Tags: command-line, batch, cmd.exe

I'm basically looking for the opposate of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47796707/how-to-extract-text-after-in-batch-file. I'm looking to extract the text before an equal sign in a string of text (or remove the text after the equal sign and the equal sign).


Example Input:

```
User=Your Friend
```

Desired Output:

```
User
```

Since the length of the text before and after the equal sign varies I cant use something like `%var:~0,-12%`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I'm looking to extract the text before an equal sign in a string of text

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set _string=User=Your Friend
echo %_string%
for /f "tokens=1 delims==" %%a in ("%_string%") do (
  echo %%a
  )
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
> test
User=Your Friend
User
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [For - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

Comment: For loops are the answer to everything

Comment: No delayed expansion required here.

Comment: @LotPings True, I just have it in my template for when it is actually needed :)