# Extract text after space in batch?

Tags: batch, batch-file

I know how to extract text after a space in batch (see here [How can I extract text before a character or string in a batch file?](https://superuser.com/questions/1337433/how-can-i-extract-text-before-a-character-or-string-in-a-batch-file)) however, this does not work with spaces. How would I extract the text 12345 in this string: `Address: 12345`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string substitution.

```
@Echo off
Set "String=Address: 12345"
set "Number=%String:* =%"
Echo number:%number%
```

The asterisk meaning any char any count up to the space is replaced with nothing.

You can use a simple for to iterate the string and get the last space seperated value set:

```
for %%a in (%String%) do set "Number2=%%a"
Echo number2:%number2%
```